Is is possible to read custom class with uproot by implementing my own python classes?
I'm trying to read custom classes from ROOT file with uproot. The custom classes is defined like
class TMdcTrack : public TObject {
private:
  // Some base types like int, double, ...
};

class TDstEvent: public TObject {
private:
  TObjArray* m_subMyClassArray;
  // Several other TObjArray storing other subclasses inherited from TObject
  // Each TObjArray contains only one kinds of subclass
};

I can now directly calling array(library='np') to retrieve an array of TObjArray, and access data through members:
f = uproot.open('myfile.root')
br = f['Event/TMyClass/m_subMyClassArray'] # get the subbranch of TMyClass

evt_arr = br.array(library='np')

"""
evt_arr:
array([<TObjArray of 4 items at 0x7f78bce90e20>,
       <TObjArray of 5 items at 0x7f78bcd307f0>,
       <TObjArray of 2 items at 0x7f78bcd33af0>, ...,
       <TObjArray of 4 items at 0x7f78a7a6d270>,
       <TObjArray of 2 items at 0x7f78a7a6d810>,
       <TObjArray of 4 items at 0x7f78a7a6db70>], dtype=object)
"""

evt0_tobj0 = evt_arr[0][0]
"""
evt0_tobj0.members
{'m_trackId': 0,
 'm_helix': array([-0.05322271,  3.93592595, -0.91241798, -0.62032322,  0.48499151]),
 'm_err': array([ 1.88426648e-04,  8.48882587e-06, -5.83950065e-05,  3.39065853e-04,
        -6.70909838e-06,  4.19001986e-07, -3.03953170e-06,  1.38228700e-05,
        -2.66499054e-07,  2.29620398e-05, -7.89795570e-05,  1.34158043e-06,
         3.52230542e-02, -6.73749896e-04,  1.43196726e-05]),
 'm_stat': 100,
 'm_chi2': 28.47357177734375,
 'm_ndof': 31,
 'm_nster': 19,
 'm_nlayer': 0,
 'm_firstLayer': 1,
 'm_lastLayer': 42}
"""

But if I read data through python loop, the performance will be unacceptable.
I understand that those members can't be read as arrays directly since they aren't stored in sequential way. But is there any method or instruction (such as implementing my own uproot classes) that can allow me to restructure such data format to arrays?
Thanks!

I'm writing a comment because this is not a full answer, but if you want this to be readable as arrays without Python in the loop, you'll have to change the data structure before writing it. Perhaps this will be as simple as enabling splitLevel=999, perhaps you'll need to make simpler objects without TObjArrays. (If you're thinking of fast-reading with AwkwardForth, that can't be used here because of the TObjArrays.)
